# Text not converting to String Hadoop Java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to convert Text to String in my reduce function but its not working. I tried the same logic in Map function and it worked perfectly, but when I tried to apply this logic in my reduce function it is giving error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 1

My Map code is like this

```
public static class OutDegreeMapper2 
    extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>
{

    private Text word = new Text();
    private Text word2 = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        String oneLine = value.toString();
        String[] parts = oneLine.split("\t");
        word.set(parts[0]);
        String join = parts[1]+",from2";
        word2.set(join);

        context.write(word, word2);
    }
}
```

My reduce function is like this

```
public static class OutDegreeReducer 
    extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> 
{
    private Text word = new Text();
    String merge ="";
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, 
                                Context context
                        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {

        for(Text val:values)
        {

            String[] x = val.toString().split(",");

            if(x[1].contains("from2")){
                merge+= x[0];
            }

        }
        word.set(merge);
        context.write(key, word);
    }
}
```

Kindly tell me why split is working in map function but not in reducer?

Comment: need stacktrace, 
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:  This would mean you are trying accessing an index in the array that does not exists.
Without more stacktrace, I cannot help here.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me what do you mean by stacktrace? I am quite new to programming so don't know about this much.

Comment: Strange this is split function is working perfectly in Map function but it is not working in reducer function. I even checked it with val.toString().contains("from2") to validate and it does not even pick it. My output shows empty values against keys.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the input text you are providing

Comment: Stacktrace => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors If you are not comfortable with Java and debugging it, then I wouldn't suggest learning MapReduce

Answer (score 0):

Very likely here

```
String[] parts = oneLine.split("\t");
word.set(parts[0]);
String join = parts[1]+",from2";
```

or here

```
String[] x = val.toString().split(",");

if(x[1].contains("from2")){
    merge+= x[0];
}
```

when read `x[1]` or `parts[1]`  throws the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because there is no `,` and `\t` inside the string.

I suggest to check the size of the array before access the element 1.

Looking at the stacktrace you should be able to understand where is throwing the exception.

Comment: Your first mentioned part is working perfectly, i crossed checked it by removing the if condition in reducer. And it printed from2 against keys. But when I try to split the Text by converting it into string or try to check function val.toString().contains, it doesnt work. strange thing as it works in map fucntion but not in reduce.

Comment: You say there is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` right?

Comment: if the array returned by `split` is smaller that 2 elements an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. I only see 2 points in your code where this can happens. Just add in the statement `if (x[1].contains("from2"))` a check like `if (x.length > 1 && x[1].contains("from2"))`. do the same for the other `parts[1]`

Comment: When I added x[0] to the code directly, it worked. Output shows from1 against keys. But when I try to use val.toString.contains("from2") it doesn't works. same case with split. Split and contains don't work here

Comment: Waiting for you reply sir :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  if(x.length() > 1 && x[1].contains("from2")){
        merge+= x[0];
    }
```

Do this:

```
if(x.length() > 1 && x[1].contains("from2")){
    merge+= x[0];
}
```

Comment: I tried to use x.length() function and it gives following error BFS.java:110: error: cannot find symbol int j=x.length();